# Patching executable in lldb? Equivalent of "gdb --write"?

Tags: binary, patch, lldb

I know I can change memory content in lldb using 
something like

```
memory write -s 1 0x100000cf7 0x7f
```

but I would like this to be reflected in the
original executable; i.e. I'd like to patch
the binary. On gdb you could accomplish this by 
the command

```
set {unsigned char} 0x00000000004006f3 = 0x7f
```

and calling gdb with

```
gdb --write.
```

Is there an equivalent command/switch in lldb?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such feature in lldb.